# Get data from Curl response coming in html formate PHP

Tags: php, curl, caching, magento2

I am updating some records using Curl, after sending a request on the response I am getting HTML formate data. I want to check the response that, what is the response.
My code is :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $cacheManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface');
        $cacheManager->clean('catalog_product_' . $param);
        $varnishurl = "www.exapmle.com";
        $varnishcommand = "PURGE";
        $productID = $param; // This is the Magento ProductID of the item you want to purge 

        $curl = curl_init($varnishurl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $varnishcommand);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: catalog_product_'.$productID]);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);     
        curl_close($curl);
```

OutPut: 
[image]
I want to add condition to check what is returned ? either its purged like title of response or body text.I have tried by json formate sending but no luck.

Comment: I'm sorry I coudn't git it, do you want to parse the HTML returned and know if the result of your request purged, or not purged ?

Comment: @Accountantم Yes exactly.

Comment: but without error of can't parse json error.

Comment: This is **very unreliable**, the HTML is a subject to change, we can search for some string that only exists if it's purged, and string that only exists if it's not purged. There must be a reliable API for this, I can't provide an answer since I I can't expect the returned HTML.

Comment: Regarding the "Can't parse json" error you get from the server, that indicates that the server is expecting a valid JSON string from you.

Comment: You can also include the `magento` tag to your question, that could give you better help.

Comment: I have tried by searching for a string using `strpos` but that didn't help.

Comment: `if (strpos($html, "Cashe updated successfully for the Product Id") !== false) {$done = true} else {$done = false;}`, but as I told you this is very unreliable, you MUST look for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Just change my code little bit and I got my answer. Add strip tags tag to remove HTML tags then search for what is required.

```
$data = strip_tags($result);
    if(strpos($data, '200 Purged')  !== false){     
    return 'Cache updated successfully for the Product Id '.$param;
   }else{
      return 'Some error occured during cache update for the Product Id '.$param;
   }
```